# VB.NET Form Position to Bottom

Tags: vb.net, winforms, position

It may be a stupid question...but how can I make a Windows Form to load from the Bottom of the screen in VB.NET?
I have tried using Form Location but it only have Center Screen ETC. :(
Also tried this code...but not exactly what I would like..

```
Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 400
        y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 270
        Me.Location = New Point(x, y)
```

I'm Making a App that runs In Maximized Mode so it fills the whole screen. I want the app to have its own keyboard (a form with buttons that acts like keys!) that have to appear at the bottom (like the keyboard appears on the bottom of the screen at any Android / IOS Phone

Comment: you cant have a form be maximized and **not** take up the whole screen / hiding your OSK

Comment: No, I say that IT FILLS! the whole screen. And the form that acts like a On screen Keyboard is TOP MOST :)

Comment: Maximized form is the first to start. After this, If user clicks on a textbox,  OSK form (which is top most) appears.

Comment: I don't know what are coordinates for bottom center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your form centered at the bottom of the primary screen, you can use this code in the form's Load event handler.

```
Dim x As Integer = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width) \ 2
Dim y As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height
Me.Location = New Point(x, y)
```

In your comments, you ask about positioning the form at the bottom of the screen but filling the width of the screen. You can do that like this.

```
Dim y As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height
Me.Location = New Point(0, y)
Me.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width
```

Comment: Man, Can I be the first who tells you that you're the best?

Comment: What \2 means? I never understood it.

Comment: Any ideea how to make the form to fill the WIDTH only?

Comment: @KingOfBSOD: the \ operator does integer division. It rounds the answer down to an Integer.

Comment: Thx, about making form's width the same as screen width?

Comment: @KingOfBSOD: to fill the width, set x (in the code I posted) equal to 0. Then set the width of the form to the width of the screen `Me.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width`

Comment: I updated the answer to show making the OSK fill the bottom of the screen as an alternative.